# Select from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select from 3 tables from my database, but I can't get all information I need.

This is the query I use:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "

SELECT s.db_id as sub_id
     , s.db_username
     , s.db_pass
     , s.db_subcompany
     , s.db_classid
     , s.db_companyid
     , l.db_class
     , l.db_id as cl_id
     , c.db_company
     , c.db_id as c_id
  FROM tbl_subcompany s
  JOIN tbl_companies c
    ON c.db_id = s.db_companyid
  JOIN tbl_class l
    ON l.db_id = s.db_classid
 ORDER 
    BY l.db_class ASC;

")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

This is the structure of my 3 tables.
First table structure:
[image]
Second table structure:
[image]
Third table structure:
[image]

This is what I have from my query:
[image]
I want to have the username and password for the sub company, but I can't get it.

Comment: Can you post a result of what you get and what you expect.

Comment: @Sylwit please check above

Comment: No pictures thanks. Instead, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: You might want to do a `left join` rather

Comment: Have you considered that it might be your front-end/display code that is wrong?

Comment: thx @Rahul that's work when i use left join